# Hard link to field name in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

For instance i have some entity - Product

```
 public class Product {
      ...
      private String name;
      private int count;
      private Product associatedProduct;
      ...
      // GETTERS & SETTERS

 }
```

And also i have product finder which allows to find the product by filters:

```
 public interface Finder<T> {

      Set<T> find(Filter... filters);

 }
```

And now i can execute the following code:

```
      Finder<Product> finder = ...;
      // find all products with name 'cucumber'
      Set<Product> finder.find(Filter.equals("name", "cucumber"));
```

We don't like this code because i should have the 'soft' link to field name "name" and i can't have compile time exception in case misprint or any other mistake.

For this reason i have created the code generator which generate static links to properties.

The generated class looks like:

```
      public final class $Product {
                private final String context;
                // some factory is used to instance creation 
                $PostEntity() {this.context = "";}
                $PostEntity(String context) {this.context = context;}
                public String name() { return context + "name";}
                public String count() { return context + "count";}
                public String associatedProduct() { return context + "associatedProduct";}
                public $Product associatedProductDot() { return new $Product( this.context + "associatedProduct.");}

      }
```

For now i can make the following:

```
      Set<Product> finder.find(Filter.equals(Links.PRODUCT.name() , "cucumber"));
      //or
      Set<Product> finder.find(Filter.equals(Links.PRODUCT.associatedProductDot().name() , "cucumber"));
```

It works like a charm and i happy.

I know alternative approach with using proxy objects, but it imposes additional overhead in runtime and adds some magical moment in code, so this variant does not suit me.

And finally my question:

There is a more elegant approach to implement this functionality with using java 8?

Comment: What's a `Filter`?  The only `Filter` class I can find that comes with Java has to do with logging, so I don't think that's what you're using.  If `Filter` is your own class, perhaps it could be modified to work with a functional interface instead of field names?  Then you could use lambda expressions.  Unfortunately, without this kind of information (what is `Filter` and are you able to change the class), I don't think we can give you a good answer.

Comment: What is difference what is Filter? Instead of a filter can be anything... We can pass the Map<String, Object> (instead filter) where key is object field name. The final goal is avoid strings as field name and having compile time chicking.

Comment: "What is the difference?"  You're asking how you can avoid using a string for the field name (I think), but you have a `Filter` class that seems to require a field name.  I think that whether this requirement can be changed makes a big difference to the answer.  Either that or I've completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: "name" field name is equivalent the (Links.PRODUCT.name() -> "name" ) but the second variant is more safe.

Comment: For instance we can write `finder.findByTemplate(Collections.singletonMap("name", "cucumber") )`  and second variant `finder.findByTemplate(Collections.singletonMap(Links.PRODUCT.name(), "cucumber") )`

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 has everything you need:

```
public static <C,P> Predicate<C> byProperty(Function<C,P> f, P value) {
    return component->Objects.equals(f.apply(component), value);
}
public static <C> Set<C> find(Collection<? extends C> c, Predicate<? super C> p) {
    return c.stream().filter(p).collect(Collectors.<C>toSet());
}
```

The standard `interface` for filtering is called [`Predicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) and the first method above allows you to create arbitrary `Predicate`s for matching a property of a component type `C`. The second method shows how you can get a `Set` of matching components out of a `Collection` using the [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) API. Then you can use it like this:

```
List<Product> list;
```

…

```
Set<Product> set=find(list, byProperty(Product::getName, "foo"));
```

or

```
Set<Product> set=find(list, byProperty(Product::getCount, 42));
```

Note that this is type safe and contains [compile-time checked references (your “hard links”)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to your properties. The only difference to what you have asked for is that they refer to the getter method rather than to the field names, as a) field references are not supported and b) your fields are `private` anyway.

---

Note that you can augment these methods by another factory allowing to provide a value-predicate rather than a constant:

```
public static <C,P> Predicate<C> matchProp(
                                 Function<C,P> f, Predicate<? super P> value) {
    return component->value.test(f.apply(component));
}
```

This allows use cases like:

```
    Set<Product> set=find(list, matchProp(Product::getCount, count -> count>100));
```

<sup>See [Lambda Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)</sup>
or

```
    Set<Product> set=find(list, matchProp(Product::getName, String::isEmpty));
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest thing is to provide your own implementation of the `Filter` interface. Since I don't know your `Filter` interface, I have to make an assumption about how it looks like. Here is my assumption:

```
public interface Filter<T> {
    boolean matches(T t);
}
```

By the way, I think the interface `Finder` should instead look like this:

```
public interface Finder<T> {
    Set<T> find(Filter<? super T>... filters);
}
```

So, you could have a class like this:

```
public final class ProductFilters {
    private ProductFilters() { /* Utility class */ }
    public static Filter<Product> byName(final String name) {
        return new Filter() {
             public boolean matches(Product t) {
                 return name.equals(t.getName());
             }
        }
    }
}
```

You could even put this inside class Product, which can make it a little bit nicer:

```
public class Product {
     private String name;
     public static final class Filters {
         private Filters() { /* Utility Class */ }
         public static Filter<Product> byName(final String name) {
             return new Filter() {
                  public boolean matches(final Product t) {
                      return name.equals(t.name);
                  }
             };
         }
     }
}
```

And yes, Java 8 makes this stuff nicer, the explicit anonymous class can syntactically be replaced by a lambda, like this:

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    public static final class Filters {
        private Filters() { /* Utility Class */ }
        public static Filter<Product> byName(final String name) {
            return t -> name.equals(t.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Your code that uses the filters could now look like this:

```
Set<Product> cucumbers = finder.find(Product.Filters.byName("cucumber"));
```

The `Filter<T>` interface is present in Java 8 in package `java.util.function`. It's name there is `Predicate<T>`, and the essential part looks like this:

```
public interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean test(T t);
}
```

If the products that are to be filtered can be made available as `Stream` either directly, or via a `Collection`, you can use the new `java.util.stream` API for filtering. For the example I assume that the products to be filtered are in a Set, too. The code that filters products could look like this:

```
Set<Product> potentialCucumbers = ...;
// Inline lambda:
Set<Product> cucumbers = potentialCucumbers.stream().filter(p -> "cucumber".equals(p.getName())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
// Stored lambda as above:
Set<Product> cucumbers = potentialCucumbers.stream().filter(Product.Filters.byName("cucumber")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I really like static imports for that stuff as they can significantly reduce line length. With static imports it looks like this:

```
Set<Product> potentialCucumbers = ...;
// Inline lambda:
Set<Product> cucumbers = potentialCucumbers.stream().filter(p -> "cucumber".equals(p.getName())).collect(toSet());
// Stored lambda as above:
Set<Product> cucumbers = potentialCucumbers.stream().filter(byName("cucumber")).collect(toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use predicates rather than your Filter classes. They make for cleaner code. I would also suggest making commonly used properties like "name" or "owner" into interfaces that provide predicates for searchability. For instance, for the "name" and "owner" properties you might have two interfaces called "Named" and "Owned":

```
public interface Named {
    public String getName();

    public void setName(String name);

    static <T extends Named> Predicate<T> nameEquals(Class<T> clazz, String s){
        return ((p) -> { 
            if (s == null){
                return p.getName() == null;
            }
            return s.equals(p.getName());
        }); 
    }
}

public interface Owned {
    public String getOwner();

    public void setOwner(String owner);

    public static <T extends Owned> Predicate<T> ownerEquals(Class<T> clazz, String s){
        return ((p) -> { 
            if (s == null){
                return p.getOwner() == null;
            }
            return s.equals(p.getOwner());
        });     
    }
}
```

Then your Product class implements these interfaces, along with a couple simple convenience methods for calling the interface static methods:

```
public class Product implements Named, Owned{
    private String name;
    private String owner;

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner){
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Predicate<Product> nameEquals(String s){
        return Named.nameEquals(Product.class, s);  
    }

    public static Predicate<Product> ownerEquals(String s){
        return Owned.ownerEquals(Product.class, s); 
    }   
}
```

And voila, your Product is searchable. Then your find() method's signature changes to take a predicate:

```
public interface Finder<T> {
    Set<T> find(Predicate p);
}
```

One of the wonderful things about predicates is how easy they are to combine and compound with one another. For example, let's say we want to find() any products named "cucumber" who aren't owned by "john", or any products owned by "john" with any other names. The call to find() is pretty clean and understandable:

```
finder.find(
    Product.nameEquals("cucumber")
        .and(Product.ownerEquals("john").negate())
    .or(
        Product.ownerEquals("john")
            .and(Product.nameEquals("cucumber").negate())
    )
);
```

I should be pretty clear what this block of code is doing. I used the indentation to try and make it clearer how they combine. We can combine the different predicates to our hearts' content.